# Gaming, mouse get crazy when left click

Tags: mouse

I am on kubuntu with an home built computer tower, I have a problem with my mouse, whenever I use the left button and do a small movement, the mouse get totally crazy, it makes in almost (to not say every) games, I tried (minecraft, tf2, cs..). But on the desktop when I left click and move to make a small rectangle (I dont know how we call that in english), I have no problems. Thanks you advance for every ideas you could give me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first off, what exactly do you mean by crazy behavior? Explain exactly what it does. Meanwhile,  I may suggest couple things. See if those work.

1. Go to Ubuntu Software Center and search GPointing, it should show you a software called "Pointing Devices." This is device settings manager for mouse and touchpad. Try changing up some settings there. For example,  try disable edge scrolling, or try change speed. Just try to play with settings,  see what it does.
2. Have you tried another mouse? It could be a hardware issue, too. I wouldn't think it is,  because you said it works on desktop ok. But just try another mouse. See if behavior changes.
3. Try changing settings in the games, lower graphics perhaps.

Let me know if this helps in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the mouse driver package:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-mouse && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-mouse
```